How can I set SwiftUI so that the device does not switch off?
I'm working on a Pomdoro function, my only problem is that while the timer is running, the iPhone or iPad switches off because you're not using the device. How can I change this in my code so that it doesn't switch off while the timer is active, or can I use a switch to decide for myself whether I want this or not?
Many thanks in advance for your help
I had first tried to activate background processing in XCode and thought that it would be automatically converted, but unfortunately that didn't help.
Here is my Code:
struct FocusView: View {
    @State var progress: Double = 0
    @State var isTimerViewPresented: Bool = false
    
    @AppStorage("focusTime") private var focusTime: Double = 0
    @State private var workDuration: Double = 25
    @State private var pauseDuration: Double = 5
    
    @AppStorage("modus") private var modus: String = "work"
    
    @State var isRunning: Bool = false
    @State var pausenint: Int = 2
    
    @State var wiederholungen_Int: Int = 0
    @Binding var repetitions: Double
    
    @AppStorage("totalWorkTime") private var totalWorkTime: Double = 0
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State var isCompleteWorkTimeShow: Bool = false
    
    @State private var showCompletionSheet: Bool = false
    @State private var totalFocusTime: TimeInterval = 0
    
    func convertSecondsToTime(timeInSeconds: Int) -> String {
        let minutes = timeInSeconds / 60
        let seconds = timeInSeconds % 60
        return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        CircularProgressView_pomodoro(progress: $progress, modus: modus)
                        
                        Text(convertSecondsToTime(timeInSeconds: Int(focusTime)))
                            .font(.custom("ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 70))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation {
                                    isTimerViewPresented.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                            .sheet(isPresented: $isTimerViewPresented) {
                                TimerView(
                                    progress: $progress,
                                    isTimerViewPresented: $isTimerViewPresented,
                                    sliderValue: $workDuration,
                                    sliderValue_pause: $pauseDuration,
                                    sliderValue_wiederholungen: $repetitions,
                                    focusTime: $focusTime, modus: $modus, pause: $pausenint, wiederholungen: $wiederholungen_Int
                                )
                                .presentationBackground(.clear)
                            }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: resetTimer) {
                        Image(systemName: "backward")
                            .font(.system(size: 42))
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: toggleTimer) {
                        Image(systemName: isRunning ? "pause" : "play")
                            .font(.system(size: 42))
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: skipTimer) {
                        Image(systemName: "forward")
                            .font(.system(size: 42))
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                if isCompleteWorkTimeShow {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Gesamte Arbeitszeit: \(convertSecondsToTime(timeInSeconds: Int(totalWorkTime)))")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)

                        Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                totalWorkTime = 0
                            }
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            updateTimer()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showCompletionSheet) {
                   CompletionView(totalFocusTime: totalFocusTime, onDismiss: {
                       showCompletionSheet = false
                   })
               }
    }
    
    private func resetTimer() {
        focusTime = modus == "work" ? workDuration * 60 : pauseDuration * 60
        progress = 0
        isRunning = false
    }
    
    private func toggleTimer() {
        isRunning.toggle()
    }
    
    private func skipTimer() {
        focusTime = 0
        updateTimer()
    }
    
    private func updateTimer() {
        if isRunning && repetitions > 0 {
            if focusTime > 0 {
                focusTime -= 1
                if modus == "work" {
                    totalWorkTime += 1
                    totalFocusTime += 1
                }
                progress = 1.0 - (focusTime / (modus == "work" ? workDuration * 60 : pauseDuration * 60))
            } else {
                switchMode()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func switchMode() {
        if modus == "work" {
            modus = "pause"
            focusTime = pauseDuration * 60
            scheduleNotification(for: modus)
        } else {
            modus = "work"
            focusTime = workDuration * 60
            repetitions -= 1
            if repetitions > 0 {
                scheduleNotification(for: modus)
            } else {
                completeSession()
            }
        }
        progress = 0
    }
    
    private func completeSession() {
        isRunning = false
        showCompletionSheet = true
    }
    
    private func scheduleNotification(for mode: String) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Pomodoro Timer"
        content.body = NSLocalizedString(mode == "work" ? "Zeit, wieder an die Arbeit zu gehen!" : "Zeit für eine Pause!", comment: "Pomodoro timer notification")
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "PomodoroTimer", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
}



Timer does not work in the background no matter what you do. It will die after a few seconds maybe up to a minute. Background processing works with specific “background modes”

You can use isIdleTimerDisabled .
Depending on how you've set your app up:
var body: some View {
  Text("Hi there")
    .onAppear { UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true }
    .onDisappear { UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false }
}

Or I've added it to AppDelegate in SwiftUI.
Just remember to set it to false once you're done with it.
